# The given path's format is not supported - IE8

Tags: c#, asp.net

Trying to upload an excel file. The code works fine in chrome & firefox. It throws up the above error in IE8. How can I fix this.

```
private const string ExcelUploadPath = "~/UploadedFiles/";

private void SomeFunction()
{
  string dirPath = Server.MapPath(ExcelUploadPath);      
  string ErrorMsg = SaveUploadedFile(fupCtrl, dirPath)
}

private string SaveUploadedFile(FileUpload fupCtrl, string dirPath)
    {
        try
        {
            string sFileName = "";
            Random ranObj = null;
            int nRandomNum = 0;
            ranObj = new Random();
            nRandomNum = ranObj.Next();
            sFileName = fupCtrl.PostedFile.FileName;
            sFileName = sFileName.Substring(0, sFileName.LastIndexOf(".") - 1);
            sFileName = sFileName + "_" + nRandomNum.ToString();
            sFileName = sFileName + 
                 fupCtrl.FileName.Substring(fupCtrl.FileName.LastIndexOf("."));

            fupCtrl.SaveAs(dirPath + sFileName); //exception here

            return sFileName;            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          return ex.Message.ToString();       
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [FileUpload.PostedFile.FileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.filename(v=vs.110).aspx)  returns the full file name on the client (including path)

The [Path class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx) offers numerous methods to work with strings that represent paths.

```
  sFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fupCtrl.PostedFile.FileName);
  sFileName += "_" + nRandomNum.ToString();
  sFileName += Path.GetExtension(fupCtrl.FileName);
  fupCtrl.SaveAs(Path.Combine(dirPath, sFileName));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it can be work.

```
 private const string ExcelUploadPath = "~//UploadedFiles//";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
HttpPostedFile postedFile = context.Request.Files[FileObject];                
                string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(postedFile.FileName);
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please put at least one explanatory line on top of your Cod.e and ensure its either your intellectual work or is cited properly